# Filtering elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, pattern-matching

Suppose that I have a list

```
{{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, 
{{2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}}
```

I want to make a new list that only contains the entries for which the first component of each pair does not repeat itself. So for example, the element

```
{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {2, 4}}
```

would be eliminated since `2` appears in the first component of both `{2,1}` and `{2,4}`. Likewise, `{{2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}}` will also be eliminated. Is there a simple condition I can use with the `Select` function to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Another rather interesting way:

```
z = {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 4},
    {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}};

Select[z, Length[Union[#[[All, 1]]]] == Length[#[[All, 1]]] &]

(*{{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}}*)
```

As noted below by Mr.Wizard, the function can be made slightly faster as such:

```
Select[z, Length@Union@#[[All, 1]] == Length@# &]
```

And as Simon Woods points out, it can made even a touch faster using `DeleteDuplicates` due to the unnecessary sorting:

```
Select[z, Length@DeleteDuplicates@#[[All, 1]] == Length@# &]
```

Comment: Seems the most obvious to me.

Comment: A bit shorter and faster: `Select[z, Length @ Union @ #[[All, 1]] == Length @ # &]`

Comment: Using `DeleteDuplicates` instead of `Union` will probably be faster, as it doesn't need to sort.

Answer (score 8):

```
 lst = {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, 
        {{2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}};
```

Can use

```
 Pick[lst, (DeleteDuplicates[#] == #) & /@ Map[First, lst, {2}]]
 Pick[lst, (DeleteDuplicates[#] == #) & /@ lst[[All, All, 1]]]
```

or

```
 Select[lst, (DeleteDuplicates[First /@ #] == First /@ #) &]
 Select[lst, (DeleteDuplicates[#[[All,1]]] == #[[All,1]]) &]
```

or

```
 Cases[lst, {{a_, _}, {b_, _}, {c_, _}} /; a != b != c]
```

or

```
 DeleteCases[lst, {___, {a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}, ___}]
```

or

```
 lst /. {___, {a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}, ___} :> Sequence[]
```

all give

```
 (* {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}} *)
```

Comment: Are you planning to add comparative timings?

Comment: @Mr.W, I wasn't. It would be a good idea; but don't have time this afternoon.

Comment: I added timings to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Same idea as kguler, different formulation:

```
lst = {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}},
       {{2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}};

Pick[#, Signature /@ #[[All, All, 1]], 1 | -1] & @ lst
```

> ```
> {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}}
> ```

On relatively short sublists `UnsameQ` should be faster than `Signature`:

```
Pick[#, UnsameQ @@@ #[[All, All, 1]]] & @ lst
```

---

Here are comparative timings for all methods posted so far, with the exception of `Cases[lst, {{a_, _}, {b_, _}, {c_, _}} /; a != b != c]` because that does not scale.  I also changed `lst /. {___, {a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}, ___} :> Sequence[]` to apply only to level 1 because otherwise it is orders of magnitude slower.

Functions are given in increasing order of speed as tested:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := 
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

lst = RandomInteger[19, {2500, 7, 2}]; (*sample data*)

Select[lst, (DeleteDuplicates[First /@ #] == First /@ #) &] // timeAvg

Replace[lst, {___, {a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}, ___} :> Sequence[], {1}] // timeAvg

DeleteCases[lst, {___, {a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}, ___}] // timeAvg

Select[lst, Length[Union[#[[All, 1]]]] == Length[#[[All, 1]]] &] // timeAvg

Pick[lst, (DeleteDuplicates[#] == #) & /@ Map[First, lst, {2}]] // timeAvg

Pick[lst, (DeleteDuplicates[#] == #) & /@ lst[[All, All, 1]]] // timeAvg

Pick[#, Signature /@ #[[All, All, 1]], 1 | -1] &@lst // timeAvg

Pick[#, UnsameQ @@@ #[[All, All, 1]]] &@lst // timeAvg
```

> 0.01684
>
> 0.01248
>
> 0.01248
>
> 0.007864
>
> 0.005736
>
> 0.003992
>
> 0.003248
>
> 0.0020464

**Update:** my second data set was poor as nothing would be selected.  Timings updated using a data set which results in about 50% selection.

With data of a very different shape: `lst = RandomInteger[2*^6, {25, 1700, 2}];` the order changes quite a bit:  (functions tested in the same order as above)

> 0.00824
>
> 127.624
>
> 144.831
>
> 0.003624
>
> 0.02496
>
> 0.005864
>
> 0.008864
>
> 0.1654

With long sublists the pattern-based tests are revealed to be very slow, and as I expected (from prior testing) `UnsameQ` falls way behind `Signature`.  Kale's function is the fastest; it can be made a bit faster (and shorter) by rewriting as:

```
Select[lst, Length @ Union @ #[[All, 1]] == Length @ # &]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a comprehensive array of list manipulation techniques presented on this page. The `DuplicateFreeQ` function was introduced two years later for this task and enables concise code.

[image]

```
alist = {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{2, 
    1}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}}

MatrixForm /@ alist
```

[image]

To remove a matrix with duplicated entries in the first column, each of the following works.

```
Pick[alist, DuplicateFreeQ@#[[All, 1]] & /@ alist]

Select[alist, DuplicateFreeQ@#[[All, 1]] &]
```

> {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}}

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this using `GroupBy`, `DuplicateFreeQ` (as pointed out, @Syed) and `Lookup`:

```
alist = {{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{2, 
    1}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 2}}}

MatrixForm /@ alist

Lookup[GroupBy[alist, DuplicateFreeQ@#[[All, 1]] &], True]
```

[image]

Or using `GatherBy`:

```
GatherBy[alist, DuplicateFreeQ@#[[All, 1]] &][[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```mma
Timing[Dimensions[Select[list, DuplicateFreeQ[#1[[All,1]]] & ]]]

{10.0469, {7197882, 3, 2}}

Timing[Dimensions[Select[list, 
    Max[Tally[#1[[All,1]]][[All,2]]] <= 1 & ]]]

{25.2344, {7197882, 3, 2}}
```

The **Tally** version was written ro provide a version that ought to have worked even in Mathematica version 8.