# How do I delete all items that occur more than once?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

DeleteDuplicates works fine but leaves a single copy of the duplicated item. I need to remove all items that occur more than once i.e. `{{1,2},{1,2},{3,4}}` -> `{3,4}`. There must be a one-liner.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37936/how-to-get-list-of-duplicates-when-using-deleteduplicates, then delete all elements that are in both lists.

Comment: Related: [(1290)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1290/121), [(15776)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15776/121), [(18100)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18100/121),  [(37936)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37936/121)

Answer (score 25):

Here is a test list:

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}
```

Here is one way then:

```
GroupBy[Tally[lst], Last][1][[All, 1]]

(* {{3, 4}, {7, 8}} *)
```

The same idea using purely associations:

```
Keys[GroupBy[Counts[lst], Identity][1]]

(* {{3, 4}, {7, 8}} *)
```

A somewhat more efficient method can be this:

```
Pick[lst, Lookup[Counts[lst], lst], 1]

(* {{3, 4}, {7, 8}} *)
```

Comment: You deserve a medal. I modified your single line to do a real-world job:  GroupBy[Tally[shortListNew, #1[[9]] == #2[[9]] &], Last][1][[All, 1]];

Comment: @Boris Glad it worked for you. Re: modified - it is often better to describe your original problem, since over-simplification may lead to valid solutions to the toy problem being unusable for a real one. Hope this was not the case for other solutions either.

Answer (score 17):

Counting the times each element appears and then selecting all the elements that appear only once:

```
deleteDuplicates[list_] := First /@ Cases[Tally[list], {_, 1}]

deleteDuplicates[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}}]
```

> `{{3, 4}}`

Comment: Also works as `Cases[Tally[list], {x_, 1} :> x]`

Answer (score 10):

This question is the inverse of [How to get list of duplicates when using DeleteDuplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37936/121) and in similar manner to my [second answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37955/121) there, if sorting is allowed we may be able to produce a more efficient method.

```
uniques[p_] :=
  With[{sp = Sort@p},
    Ordering @ Reverse @ sp //
     Unitize @ Subtract[1, Differences @ #] & //
      Pick[sp, Prepend[#, 1]*Append[#, 1], 1] &
  ]
```

Tested:

```
{{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {2, 0}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}} // uniques
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}}
> ```

Performance:   (*oops, forgot to include my test data!*)

```
SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomInteger[999, {1*^6, 2}];

uniques[lst] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.293465, 368513}
> ```

Compared to other methods posted:

```
First /@ Cases[Tally[lst], {_, 1}]       // Length // AbsoluteTiming
GroupBy[Tally[lst], Last][1][[All, 1]]   // Length // AbsoluteTiming
Keys[GroupBy[Counts[lst], Identity][1]]  // Length // AbsoluteTiming
Pick[lst, Lookup[Counts[lst], lst], 1]   // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.17172, 368513}
> {1.26163, 368513}
> {4.21019, 368513}
> {2.83746, 368513}
> ```

Finally J.M.'s sort-based method, though I had to [substitute](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/121) my own function for `Nothing` in version 10.1.0:

```
Nothing = Sequence[];  (* for versions prior to 10.2 *)

Join @@ Replace[Split[Sort[lst]], v_ /; Length[v] > 1 :> Nothing, 1] // 
  Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.952435, 368513}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

```
removeDuplicates[l_List] := 
 Select[Tally[l], Last[#] === 1 &][[All, 1]]

lst = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};

removeDuplicates[lst]
(* {{3, 4}, {7, 8}} *)
```

### Performances:

```
lst = RandomInteger[99, {100000, 2}];

First@RepeatedTiming[
  removeDuplicates[lst]
  , 5]
```

> 0.0873

```
First@RepeatedTiming[
  GroupBy[Tally[lst], Last][1][[All, 1]]
  , 5]
```

> 0.0826

```
First@RepeatedTiming[
  Keys[GroupBy[Counts[lst], Identity][1]]
  , 5]
```

> 0.111

```
First@RepeatedTiming[
  Pick[lst, Lookup[Counts[lst], lst], 1]
  , 5]
```

> 0.230

```
deleteDuplicates[list_] := First /@ Cases[Tally[list], {_, 1}]

First@RepeatedTiming[
  deleteDuplicates[lst]
  , 5]
```

> 0.089

```
First@RepeatedTiming[
  Cases[Tally@lst, {{a_, b_}, 1} :> {a, b}]
  , 5]
```

> 0.0821

Answer (score 5):

Time for some fancy pattern matching it seems:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}; (* Leonid's test list *)

list // RightComposition[
   Sort,
   ReplaceRepeated[
      #,
      RuleDelayed[
         { f___, Longest @ Repeated [ l:{ _Integer, _Integer }, { 2, Infinity } ], b___ },
         { f, b }
      ]
   ]&
]
```

> {{3, 4}, {7, 8}}

Or indeed simpler and more boringly:

```
Cases[ Tally @ list, {{a_, b_}, 1} :> {a, b} ]
```

> {{3, 4}, {7, 8}}

Comment: The first one doesn't work if there are more than two of a kind. With `ReplaceRepeated` it works if there are an even number of a kind, but not if there is an odd number of a kind.

Comment: @Pickett Thank you. It's fixed now in a nicer way I hope.

Answer (score 4):

A caveat of the following solution is the need to sort, but it does well otherwise:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};
Join @@ Replace[Split[Sort[list]], v_ /; Length[v] > 1 :> Nothing, 1]
   {{3, 4}, {7, 8}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};

Pick[#[[All, 1]], Length /@ #, 1] & @ Gather[lst]
```

> {{3, 4}, {7, 8}}

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};


Keys @ DeleteCases[Except @ 1] @ Merge[Length] @ MapApply[{##} -> {##} &] @ lst
```

or

```
Keys @ Select[Length @ Last @ # == 1 &] @ Normal @ PositionIndex[lst]
```

Both give

{{3, 4}, {7, 8}}

**Addendum**

Thanks to @bmf:

```
Keys @ Select[Counts[list], # == 1 &]
```

{{3, 4}, {7, 8}}

Comment: Nicely done and it's a (+1) from me. For completeness, maybe you could add `Keys@Select[Counts[list], # == 1 &]` since you used `Keys`

Comment: Thank you very much - I couldn't  see the forest for the trees

Comment: It was a very nice answer in any case :-)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, a old fashion way to do it :

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};

{listCopied, listOfDuplicates} = 
 Fold[{
      Append[#1[[1]], #2], 
      If[MemberQ[#1[[1]], #2],Append[#1[[2]], #2], #1[[2]]]
      } &,
      {{}, {}},
      list] 

Select[list, ! MemberQ[listOfDuplicates, #] &]
```

> {{3, 4}, {7, 8}}

While scanning `list` , `Fold[...]` constructs two lists :
 - one which is the list of the elements seen (`Append[#1[[1]], #2]`)
 - one with the duplicates elements (`If[MemberQ[#1[[1]], #2],Append[#1[[2]], #2], #1[[2]]]`)

Answer (score 2):

Some extra fun stuff.

With

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};
```

we have

1.

```
Reap[Sow[1, #], _, Pick[#1, #2, {1}] &][[2]] &@list // 
 DeleteCases[#, {}] &
```

2. list //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[Repeated[x_, {2, Infinity}],
   y___]} :> {y}

The above return

{{3, 4}, {7, 8}}

3.

```
ArrayReshape[
 Cases[Split[
   Sort[list]], {_}], {(Length /@ list)[[1]], (Length /@ list)[[1]]}]
```

> {{3, 4}, {7, 8}}