# How to remove duplicate elements

Tags: list-manipulation

How to remove duplicate elements? I want to delete all the same elements in a list. For example, list `{1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1}`, I want to get `{3,4,5}`.

And using `DeleteDuplicates` function can not achieve the desired purpose:
    DeleteDuplicates[{1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}]

I know this method at present: `{1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1} // Tally // Cases [{x_, 1}:> x]`, but I also want to know more ingenious methods.

Comment: I think your `Tally/*Cases` method is pretty cool!

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107483/how-do-i-delete-all-items-that-occur-more-than-once)

Comment: for fun: `{1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1} //. {a___, b_, c___, b_, d___} :> DeleteCases[{a, c, d}, b]`.

Comment: @user1066 Thanks for linking that.  This appears to be a duplicate and I am marking it as such.  If I have missed an important distinction please let me know and I shall reopen.

Comment: Also for fun (revised): `Reap[Sow[1,list], _, Pick[#1,#2, {1}]&][[2]]`

Comment: How ironic is it that a question about removing duplicates is a duplicate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
list = {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1};

Keys@Select[Counts[list], # == 1 &]
(* {3, 4, 5} *)
```

Comment: Or more functional perhaps: ```Keys@Select[Counts[list], EqualTo[1]]```

Comment: @SHuisman If you want to go operator, go all the way :-) `Keys@Select[EqualTo[1]]@Counts[list]`

Comment: `Keys@*Select[EqualTo[1]]@*Counts` is even more operator.

Comment: I like that this will preserve order.  Several of the methods shown below do not.  For example, switch the position of 3 and 4 and re-run the methods below.  Instead of {4,3,5}, they return {3,4,5}.  The method from OP also preserves the order.

Answer (score 8):

```
With[{t = Tally[#]}, Pick[t[[All, 1]], t[[All, 2]], 1]] &
```

Should outperform, hardly "ingenious "...

Answer (score 7):

Without pattern matching:

```
Sort[{1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}] // 
  Split // 
  Select[Length[#] == 1 &] //
  Flatten[#, 1] &
```

Answer (score 7):

For variety:

```
lst = {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1};

lst //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[Repeated[x_, {2, ∞}], a___]} :> {a}
```

> {3, 4, 5}

Answer (score 5):

A Rube Goldberg solution:

```
☺1 /: {♯♯___, ☺1 @ ♯_, ♯♯♯___} := {♯♯, ♯♯♯} /. ♯ | ☺1 @ ♯ -> (## &[])
☺2 = (☺3 @ ♯_ := (☺3 @ ♯ = ☺1 @ ♯; ♯); ☺3 /@ #) &;

☺2 @ {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}
```

> {3, 4, 5}

Comment: I LOL'd. +1 internet cookie for you.

Comment: I LOL'd. +1 internet cookie for you.