# Pattern matching for repeated elements

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Is there a pattern that can match repeated elements that appear more than twice in a row?

For the sake of example let's say I want to use pattern matching to delete subsequent duplicate:

```
l = {1,2,2,3,4};

l/.{b___,x_,x_,r___}->{b,r}

(*{1,3,4}*)
```

But

```
l = {1,2,2,2,3,4};

l/.{b___,x_,x_,r___}->{b,r}

(*{1,2,3,4}*)
```

I can try to use Repeated, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
l = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4};

l /. {b___, x_, (x_) .., r___} -> {b, r}

(*{1,2,3,4}*)
```

Am I using it wrong?

Comment: Related: [How to remove duplicate elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215552/106) where @Szabolcs has [given](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215554/106) `Keys@Select[Counts[l], # == 1 &]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `Longest` pattern command to find the longest repeated sequence that matches the pattern.

```
l = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4};

l /. {b___, x_, Longest[(x_) ..], r___} :> {b, r}

(*{1, 3, 4}*)
```

Comment: That's helpful. However, when I try it on l={1,1,1,2} the result is {1,1,2}, and not {2} as I would expect.

Comment: `l={1,1,1,2}` returns `{2}` when I test it. Are you sure that both the `b` and `r` have three blanks?

Comment: My bad, I had missed the "repeated" on the Longest pattern. It does work!

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility is to use [`SequenceReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace):

```
SequenceReplace[{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4}, {x_, x_ ..} -> Sequence[]]
```

> {1, 3, 4}

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

```
l = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4};
l /. {b___, x_, (x_) .., r___} -> {{b}, {r}}
(* {{1}, {2, 3, 4}} *)
```

and you see that that `r` is ill-defined. Therefore we must restrict `r`:

```
l //. {b___, Repeated[x_, {2, 10}], Shortest@r___} :> {b, r}
(*{1, 3, 4}*)
```

Comment: Very nice debugging trick. I have already given the tick mark, but this would deserve one as well.

Answer (score 8):

You might also consider using the two-argument form of [`Repeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) for finer control:

```
{1, 2, 2, 3, 4}  /. {a___, Repeated[x_, {2, ∞}], b___} :> {a, b}
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 4}
> ```

```
SequenceReplace[{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4}, {Repeated[x_, {2, ∞}]} -> Sequence[]]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 4}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Not pattern matching, but one other way:

```
Cases[Split@l2, {x_}:>x]
```

> {1, 3, 4}

Answer (score 4):

```
Cases[{a_, 1} :> a] @ Tally @ list
```

{1, 3, 4}

Or:

```
Keys @ Select[SameAs @ 1] @ Counts @ list
```

{1, 3, 8}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Select` and `Count`:

```
l = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4};

Select[l, Count[l, #] == 1 &]

(*{1, 3, 4}*)
```

Also, using `ReplaceAll`:

```
f = # /. x_Integer :> If[Count[#, x] == 1, x, Nothing] &;

f@l

(*{1, 3, 4}*)
```

Also, using the third argument of `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[Normal@Counts[l], #[[2]] == 1 &, #[[All, 1]] &], True]

(*{1, 3, 4}*)
```