# Delete elements of a list with the same x value

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

Suppose we have the following list

```
data = {{0,1},{-1,2},{5,-2},{4,4},{3,0},{-1,1},{6,0.5},{7,2},{8,-5},{9,2}}
```

How can we remove all elements of this list which have the same x value? For example, in the above example, the entries {-1,2} and {-1,1} should be removed, since in both of them the x value is the same (-1).

I tried `DeleteDuplicates[data]` but it does not work.

Many thanks in advance and Merry Christmas to all!

Comment: [how-do-i-delete-all-items-that-occur-more-than-once](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107483/how-do-i-delete-all-items-that-occur-more-than-once)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Select[Counts[data[[All, 1]]]@#[[1]] == 1 &] @ data

Join @@ Select[Length@# == 1 &] @ GatherBy[data, First]

Values @ GroupBy[data, First, If[Length @ # > 1, Nothing, #[[1]]] &]

data[[Flatten @ Select[Length @ # == 1 &] @ 
   GatherBy[Range @ Length @ data, data[[#, 1]] &]]]

FixedPoint[SequenceReplace[#, b : {{a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}} :> 
    Sequence @@ DeleteCases[b, {a, _}]] &, data]
```

all give

> ```
>  {{0, 1}, {5, -2}, {4, 4}, {3, 0}, {6, 0.5`}, {7, 2}, {8, -5}, {9, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
Tally[data, First@#1 == First@#2 &] // Cases[{x_, 1} :> x]
```

gives

```
{{0, 1}, {5, -2}, {4, 4}, {3, 0}, {6, 0.5}, {7, 2}, {8, -5}, {9, 2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data[[Flatten[Select[Part[#,2]&/@Normal[PositionIndex[First/@data]],Length[#]>1&]]]]={"delThis"};
data=DeleteCases[data,{"delThis"}]

{{0, 1}, {5, -2}, {4, 4}, {3, 0}, {6, 0.5}, {7, 2}, {8, -5}, {9, 2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{3, 4}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}};
```

Using `SequenceCases` to find duplicated first elements

```
dup = SequenceCases[list, {{a_, _}, ___, {a_, _}} :> a]
```

{0, 2}

```
Select[FreeQ[dup, First[#]] &] @ list
```

{{3, 4}, {1, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{0, 1}, {-1, 2}, {5, -2}, {4, 4}, {3, 0},
       {-1, 1}, {6, 0.5}, {7, 2}, {8, -5}, {9, 2}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's pattern and using `ReplaceList` and `Pick`:

```
dup = ReplaceList[data, {___, {a_, _}, __, {a_, _}, ___} :> a]

Pick[#, FreeQ[dup, First[#]] & /@ #] &@data
```

> {{0, 1}, {5, -2}, {4, 4}, {3, 0}, {6, 0.5}, {7, 2}, {8, -5}, {9, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

```
GatherBy[data, First] // Select[EqualTo[1]@*Length] // Map[First]

data~GatherBy~First~Select~EqualTo[1]@*Length // Map[First]

GatherBy[data, First] // Cases[{a_List} :> a]

Replace[data, {x___, {a_, b_}, y___, {a_, c_}, z___} :> {x, y, 
   z}, All]

ReplaceRepeated[data, {x___, 
   PatternSequence[{a_, b_}, g___, {a_, c_}], y___} :> {x, g, y}]
```

---

> {{0, 1}, {5, -2}, {4, 4}, {3, 0}, {6, 0.5}, {7, 2}, {8, -5}, {9, 2}}